# Modify an HttpServletResponse by appending content in a Spring MVC Interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a special requirement to add a stylesheet into the content of every page in a third party portal application to make the UI consistent.

I thought about using a Spring Interceptor since the application uses Spring MVC.

This is how far I got and kept getting an Exception:

```
public class RequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {


    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        if (matches(request)) {
            OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
            o.write("Addendum".getBytes());
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception**: *java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response*

Is it possible to modify content ( i.e. the entire response body ) before it gets to the browser?

**NOTE**: The choice of using a Servlet Filter is not on the table right now!

Comment: What do you mean _add a stylesheet_?

Comment: Yes - add a style sheet directly into the HTML

Comment: You can't append something to an HTML document and expect the browser to render it. Can you clarify what your HTTP response contains at the time you want to `postHandle`? And clarify what the `"Addenum"` will contain.

Comment: So the response, pre-interceptor, contains `<html>...</html>`? What do you plan to append to that? What do you think that will do? Why do you think so? I'm trying to understand what you are trying to achieve. If by _stylesheet_ you mean _css_, that append won't work. That's not how HTML and CSS work together.

Comment: I can use regular expressions on the response body and insert extra css content just before the closing head tag.

Comment: Ok, so that won't be an append. You'll have to collect to http response, without flushing it, then insert content into it. This is non trivial and won't be easy to do with a `HandlerInterceptor`, mostly because you can't override the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` as you would in a `Filter`. Can't you add the CSS directly the JSP or whatever template strategy you are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83251/discussion-between-olaseni-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Comment: @Olaseni Have you solved the problem?